# with statement python __enter__ attribute error

Tags: python, attributeerror, with-statement

This :

```
def add_to_excel(list_to_save, file_to_save_in):

my_file = dir_path + '\\' + file_to_save_in
with openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=my_file) as links_excel:
    sheet = links_excel['Sheet1']
    for i in list_to_save:
        sheet.append(i)
    links_excel.save(filename)
    return
```

returns this:

```
      3     my_file = dir_path + '\\' + file_to_save_in
----> 4     with openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=my_file) as links_excel:
      5         sheet = links_excel['Sheet1']
      6         for i in list_to_save:

AttributeError: __enter__
```

Tried this:

> You're not using with statement and there's no close() statement so if this is not the first time you're running the code, it's likely that you haven't closed the file properly and it is still sitting in the memory and prevents access.

Edit:

Apparently closing the excel fixes it, and the with statement is not needed.

> links_excel.close()

```
def add_to_excel(list_to_save, file_to_save_in):

my_file = os.path.join(dir_path, file_to_save_in)
links_excel=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=my_file)
sheet = links_excel['Sheet1']
for i in list_to_save:
    sheet.append(i)
links_excel.save(my_file)
links_excel.close()
```

Comment: What makes you think you can use `with` here?

Comment: As a side-note, I strongly recommend using `os.path.join(dir_path, file_to_save_in)` rather than `my_file = dir_path + '\\' + file_to_save_in`. This way, your code won't break if someone tries to run it on a system other than windows.

Comment: I changed the line to this after the error appeared for the first time, is it not necessary?

Comment: The openpyxl workbook doesn't offer a context manager by default, so you can't use it with `with`  - you could add a context manager if you'd like for it to free up resources once done, but as far as I know, `load_workbook` doesn't keep the workbook open or anything, so I don't think it's worth it?

Comment: The error message is correctly telling you that you can't use `with` like that. You can only use `with` on an object that as an `__enter__` and an `__exit__` methods. For `load_workbook`, you can just write `links_excel = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=my_file)`

Comment: [Here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.0/openpyxl/reader/excel.py#L288) is the definition of the function and it doesn't seem to define a context manager as others have pointed out. If you follow to the class it return an instance of, `ExcelReader`, you'll see there is neither `__enter__()` nor `__exit__()` methods.

Comment: The reason why `load_workbook` is not designed to work with `with` is that `load_workbook` already opens and closes the file. Using a `with` block would only be useful if you needed the file to remain open for some time.

Comment: Unfortunately `openpyxl.Workbook` have no context manager support required for using with `with` keyword. To close related file and unload all related data you can remove this object by `del links_excel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [openpyxl documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)

Read an existing workbook:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['range names']
print(sheet_ranges['D18'].value)
```

This is an example on how to use the `load_workbook` method, so you don't need to use that with statement. Just use assignment.

```
def add_to_excel(list_to_save, file_to_save_in):
    
    my_file = dir_path + '\\' + file_to_save_in
    links_excel = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=my_file) 
    sheet = links_excel['Sheet1']
    for i in list_to_save:
        sheet.append(i)
    links_excel.save(filename)
    links_excel.close()
    return
```

Comment: This is what my code was like first and would return a` permissions error - access denied` after a few iterations. So I was thinking that excel my not be closing fast enough before being reopened.

Comment: in which line do you get the error? reading?

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: when writing in the excel, in a while loop

Comment: have you closed the excel? I mean is it closed in your operating system while you're writing?

Comment: links_excel.close() fixed the issue apparently. Thanks!

Comment: if you solved, then edit your post and add useful information to solve your problem, so it can be useful for other users :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is absolutely correct. However it is still possible to open a workbook using the context manager. By implementing a little interface class:

```
class Workbook(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.wb =  load_workbook(filename=path)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.wb
    
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.wb.close()
```

you can use your openpyxl workbook instance with a context manager (the with statement):

```
with Workbook(path) as wb:
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    for i in list_to_save:
        sheet.append(i)
    wb.save(filename)
```